# Usando o Ruby on Rails é possível executar funções externas no lado cliente?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lado-do-cliente, impressora

Exemplo: No computador que está com o navegador acessando a página, com a devida   permissão, executar uma função em uma DLL instalada no mesmo?

Complementando:
A minha intenção era utilizar em uma intranet, e acessar uma impressora usando a DLL fornecida pelo fabricante da mesma

Comment: O mais provável é que você: a) não precisa chamar uma dll nativa para o que quer fazer ou b) o que quer fazer não pode ser feito pela web. Qualquer que seja o caso, poderemos ajudar muito melhor se nos disser qual é a intensão.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível usando qualquer linguagem e praticamente qualquer tecnologia.

Digo praticamente porque sempre é possível alguém instalar algo que passe por cima de uma restrição fundamental em um navegador. Mas não conte com isto, a chance disto ocorrer é quase zero. E se você convencer alguém instalar algo que deixa ele vulnerável ainda terá que providenciar essa tecnologia. Ou seja, use outra solução.

Fazer coisas para *web*, ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, realmente não é a solução para todos os problemas.

Comment: Ok Maniero, a minha intenção era utilizar em uma intranet, e acessar uma impressora usando a DLL fornecida pelo fabricante da mesma.

Comment: Como eu disse, nem todos os problemas devem ser resolvidos com aplicações *web*. Se precisa fazer isto, faça uma aplicação *desktop*, o mais correto. Ou faça um serviço para instalar localmente no cliente para que a página possa se comunicar. Mas veja que isto nada estará relacionado à aplicação rodando no servidor. Será uma bela gambiarra porque você acha que [todos os problemas são pregos](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail).